# Does anyone know of software that can set a mac's resolution to only part of the screen?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, resolution

My macbook got knocked off the table ~6 months ago and landed on its corner and dented.  A few days ago about 30 rows of pixels on that same side went dead.

It's not enough for me to want to rush out and get it fixed, but I'm wondering if I can somehow just turn those pixels off

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible, any program would just adjust the entire screens resolution but it won't know that there are dead pixels so it can't solve for that.

The easiest solution is just to use an external display.